# How can I split a column that has an object onto multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, jupyter-notebook

my columns look like this:

```
A  B     objectToBeSplit
1  2  {0.223, 0.112, 0.441}
3  4  {0.423, 0.402, 0.593}
```

And I would like to have it like this:

```
A  B    C      D      E
1  2  0.223  0.112  0.441
3  4  0.423  0.402  0.593
```

How can I split the **objectToBeSplit** column in python?

Comment: What is the object? a `set`? Can you provide a reproducible constructor for the DataFrame for clarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this

```
# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 3],
    'B': [2, 4],
    'objectToBeSplit': ['{0.223, 0.112, 0.441}', '{0.423, 0.402, 0.593}']
})

# Splitting the 'objectToBeSplit' column
df[['C', 'D', 'E']] = df['objectToBeSplit'].str.strip('{}').str.split(', ', expand=True)

# Dropping the original 'objectToBeSplit' column
df = df.drop('objectToBeSplit', axis=1)
```

Approach 2:

```
# Create new columns C, D, E by splitting the values in the "objectToBeSplit" column
df[['C', 'D', 'E']] = pd.DataFrame(df['objectToBeSplit'].tolist()).applymap(float)

# Dropping the original 'objectToBeSplit' column
df = df.drop('objectToBeSplit', axis=1)

# Print the updated DataFrame
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a Series of `set`:

```
out = (df.drop(columns='objectToBeSplit')
         .join(pd.DataFrame(df['objectToBeSplit'].tolist(),
                            columns=['C', 'D', 'E']))
      )
```

Or, if you want to reassign to the same name:

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('objectToBeSplit').tolist(),
                          columns=['C', 'D', 'E']))
```

Output:

```
   A  B      C      D      E
0  1  2  0.223  0.112  0.441
1  3  4  0.423  0.402  0.593
```

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 3],
                   'B': [2, 4],
                   'objectToBeSplit': [{0.112, 0.223, 0.441},
                                       {0.402, 0.423, 0.593}],
                   })
```